# vb.net load dlls from subfolder works not on all

Tags: vb.net, dll, subdirectory

I have a project with some additional libraris, some are my own others are from Stimulsoft and DevExpress.

All the librarys are in corresponding subfolders for the librarys folder like this:
Library\GUI - for the DevExpress DLLs
Library\Stimulsoft
Library\Tools

The librays are all added to the project as reference from the subfolder like above.
Local copy = false so the dlls are not copied to /bin/Debug.

When i use something like

```
Dim Files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(AppPath, "Library\GUI"))
For Each File In Files
    If File.Contains("DevExpress") And File.EndsWith("dll") Then
        System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(File)
    End If
Next
```

All DLLs are visible in the debugger under Modules with the correct path but as soon as a DLL is used (like i open a WPF where DevExpress components are used) i get a file not found exception. FusionLog of the exception shows that it tries to access the DLL from the root directory: /bin/Debug/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v21.2.DLL. instead of /bin/Debug/Library/GUI/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v21.2.DLL.

This also does not work with DevExpress or Stimulsoft but with other DLLs in other Subfolders it does work:

```
Dim oAssembly As Reflection.Assembly = GetType(MainWindow).Assembly
Dim AppPath As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(oAssembly.Location)
Dim adSetup = New AppDomainSetup()
adSetup.ApplicationBase = AppPath
adSetup.PrivateBinPath = "Library\GUI"
Dim adDevExpress As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Devexpress", Nothing, adSetup)
```

If i set "Local Copy=True" it works but i rather not clutter the Apps Root directory.
That shows that there are no dependencies of the DevExpress DLLs missing - i also used the DeploymentTool to get the correct DLLs.

That for example works:

```
Dim qrCodeTools As System.Reflection.Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(AppPath,"Library\Tools\QRCoder.dll"))
```

Any ideas how to get it working with DevExpress and Stimulsoft the way i want?

Comment: You may need to handle `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` to redirect assembly loads to the correct folder.

Comment: It works. I assumed wrongly that Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath) does the same thing what i do in my For Each.

Comment: I think the issue is that `Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath)` will handle that specific assembly, but its references will still attempt to load from the normal set of search paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed wrongly that Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath) does the same thing what i do in my For Each.

The Solution for me is this:

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    AddHandler currentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf LoadFromSubFolder

    ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Designer erforderlich.
    InitializeComponent()
```

.......

```
Private Shared Function LoadFromSubFolder(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ResolveEventArgs) As Assembly
    Dim Anwendungspfad As String = sender.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
    Dim folderPath As String

    Dim AssemblyName As String = New AssemblyName(args.Name).Name

    If AssemblyName.ToLower.Contains("DevExpress".ToLower) Then
        folderPath = Path.Combine(Anwendungspfad, "Library\GUI")
    ElseIf AssemblyName.ToLower.Contains("stimulsoft".ToLower) Then
        folderPath = Path.Combine(Anwendungspfad, "Library\stimulsoft")
    Else
        folderPath = Anwendungspfad
    End If


    Dim assemblyPath As String = Path.Combine(folderPath, AssemblyName & ".dll")
    If Not File.Exists(assemblyPath) Then Return Nothing
    Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath)
    Return assembly
End Function
```